# Error: Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, repeater

Currently, my program in Visual Studio dynamically adds my data from my Repeater into my database.

Now I need to add the ID, my EventId and FormId, which I collected manually outside of the Repeater.

I need to add this in:

```
 sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventId;
 sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = formId;
```

However with how my code is setup, it gives an error when I add this code that says:

> Additional information: Procedure or function 'spInsFormRegistrant'
>   expects parameter '@EventId', which was not supplied.

Working code (with error code commented out):

```
 protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Events2"].ConnectionString))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
                {

                   //sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventId;
                   //sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = formId;
                    foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in RepeaterForm.Items)
                    {
                        Label lblDisplayName = rpItem.FindControl("lblDisplayName") as Label;
                        Label lblColumnName = rpItem.FindControl("lblColumnName") as Label;
                        TextBox txtColumnValue = rpItem.FindControl("txtColumnValue") as TextBox;

                        if (txtColumnValue != null)
                        {
                            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                            sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            sqlCmd.CommandText = "spInsFormRegistrant";
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();

                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lblColumnName.Text;
                            sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtColumnValue.Text;

                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            PnlNone.Visible = false;
            PnlExist.Visible = false;
            PnlSuccess.Visible = true;
            PnlFail.Visible = false;
        }
```

So I just need to know where to add in `@EventId` and `@FormId` for this to function correctly. Each time I try it, it does not work. I must be missing something small for this to not produce an error. Or maybe it is an issue with my stored procedure...?

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsFormRegistrant]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
     @EventId int,
     @FormId int,
     @ColumnName varchar(100),
    @ColumnValue varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
     declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
    declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

    set @Query = 'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)'
    set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100)'
    exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue

END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not adding the parameter for eventID and for FormID, but you should try to use a different approach. Do not create everytime the parameters. You could create them just one time before entering the foreach loop and then, inside the loop change only their value

```
// This part never changes so, set it up just one time before the loop
sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
sqlCmd.CommandText = "spInsFormRegistrant";
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventId;
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = formId;

// These twos change inside the loop, so we don't need the value here
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar);


foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in RepeaterForm.Items)
{
    Label lblDisplayName = rpItem.FindControl("lblDisplayName") as Label;
    Label lblColumnName = rpItem.FindControl("lblColumnName") as Label;
    TextBox txtColumnValue = rpItem.FindControl("txtColumnValue") as TextBox;

    if (txtColumnValue != null)
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@ColumnName"].Value = lblColumnName.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters["@ColumnValue"].Value = txtColumnValue.Text;
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Of course you don't need the call to `Parameters.Clear`

Then there is a problem in the way in which you pass the paramenters to the sp_executesql call inside the stored procedure. That system storedprocedure requires that you set the datatype for every parameter used in the query and an initialization list of these parameters.

You should write

```
...
-- Insert statements for procedure here
declare @Query nvarchar(4000)
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);

set @Query = 'INSERT into Registrant(DateCreated,EventId,FormId,'+ 
             (@ColumnName) +') values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, @EventId, @FormId, @ColumnValue)'
set @ParmDefinition = N'@ColumnValue varchar(100), @EventID int, @FormID int'
exec sp_executesql @Query, @ParmDefinition, 
                   @ColumnValue = @ColumnValue,
                   @EventID = @EventID,
                   @FormID = @FormID
```

Comment: Thanks Steve! Okay this works, but now I get the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@EventId". I think maybe my stored procedure could be the reason, but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes the problem is how you pass the parameters to sp_executesql. I will add it to the answer

Comment: That is well defined, I couldn't pick it up.

Comment: Great! That solved the error. The last issue now is that it is submitting each @ColumnValue into a new row. All of this should be in one row.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean with _in one row_?

Comment: This code now will add multiple rows of data instead of 1 row into my table. Whereas in my code before, it would add all data together from the Repeater into 1 row in my table. For example, if I had FirstName and LastName as my columns and John Smith as my data, then row 1 should have FirstName = John and LastName = Smith. This however is actually putting John in row 1 and Smith in row 2.

Answer (score 1):

You are clearing the parameters:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

You need to add them over and over:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem rpItem in RepeaterForm.Items)
{
    Label lblDisplayName = rpItem.FindControl("lblDisplayName") as Label;
    Label lblColumnName = rpItem.FindControl("lblColumnName") as Label;
    TextBox txtColumnValue = rpItem.FindControl("txtColumnValue") as TextBox;

    if (txtColumnValue != null)
    {
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "spInsFormRegistrant";
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Clear();  //that's fine, keep it

        //just put them in here
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@EventId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = eventId;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@FormId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = formId;

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lblColumnName.Text;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ColumnValue", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtColumnValue.Text;

    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and now I get the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@EventId".